# Saving rviz plugin configuration

Tags: ros, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I made an rviz panel for scaling the scene. I override `save` and `load` methods and expect saving and loading scale on saving and loading `.rviz` file. But it doesn't happen: `.rviz` file doesn't contains scale and scale is always has defualt value on startup. What is wrong?

header:

```
#pragma once

#include <rviz/panel.h>

class QLineEdit;

namespace orbiterros {
namespace rviz_plugin {

class ScalePanel : public rviz::Panel {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        ScalePanel(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

        virtual void load(const rviz::Config& config);
        virtual void save(rviz::Config config);

        static const char panel_name[];

    public Q_SLOTS:
        void setWorldScale(const float& scale);

    protected Q_SLOTS:
        void updateWorldScale();

    protected:
        QLineEdit* world_scale_editor_;
        float actual_scale_;

        static const QString world_scale_property_name;
};

}
}
```

`.cpp`:

```
#include "scale_panel.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QValidator>
#include <rviz/visualization_manager.h>
#include <OGRE/OgreSceneManager.h>
#include <QLocale>

namespace orbiterros {
namespace rviz_plugin {

constexpr char ScalePanel::panel_name[] = "scale_panel";
const QString ScalePanel::world_scale_property_name("World scale");

ScalePanel::ScalePanel(QWidget* parent):
        rviz::Panel(parent),
        world_scale_editor_(new QLineEdit),
        actual_scale_(1.0)
{
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(new QLabel(world_scale_property_name));
    world_scale_editor_->setText(QVariant(actual_scale_).toString());
    world_scale_editor_->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(1e-15, 1e3, 7));
    layout->addWidget(world_scale_editor_);
    setLayout(layout);
    bool success = connect(world_scale_editor_, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(updateWorldScale()));
    Q_ASSERT(success);
}

void ScalePanel::updateWorldScale() {
    if (not world_scale_editor_->hasAcceptableInput()) {
        ROS_DEBUG_NAMED(panel_name, "Invalid scale value (validator)");
        return;
    }

    bool ok;
    const float new_scale = QLocale(QLocale::German).toFloat(world_scale_editor_->text(), &ok);
    if (not ok) {
        ROS_DEBUG_NAMED(panel_name, "Invalid scale value (conversion)");
        return;
    }

    setWorldScale(new_scale);
}

void ScalePanel::setWorldScale(const float& scale) {
    if (scale < 1e-15 or scale > 1e3) {
        ROS_DEBUG_NAMED(panel_name, "Invalid scale value (value)");
        return;
    }

    this->vis_manager_->getSceneManager()->getRootSceneNode()->setScale(scale, scale, scale);
    ROS_DEBUG_NAMED(panel_name, "Set world scale to %f", scale);

    Q_EMIT configChanged();
}

void ScalePanel::save(rviz::Config config) {
    rviz::Panel::save(config);
    config.mapSetValue(world_scale_property_name, actual_scale_);
}

void ScalePanel::load(const rviz::Config& config) {
    rviz::Panel::load(config);
    QVariant scale;
    if (config.mapGetValue(world_scale_property_name, &scale)) {
        world_scale_editor_->setText(scale.toString());
        updateWorldScale();
    }
}

}
}

#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(orbiterros::rviz_plugin::ScalePanel, rviz::Panel)
```

[Code on Github](https://github.com/standmit/orbiterros/tree/07fed4debe57022559b59a6e36d31d50973566d0/src/rviz_plugin)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371967/saving-rviz-plugin-configuration/) by [standmit](https://answers.ros.org/users/39694/standmit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2021-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your function signature is the following:

```
virtual void save(rviz::Config config);
```

Whereas the function signature you want to override is

```
virtual void save(rviz::Config config) const;
```

See also [the docs page](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rviz/html/c++/classrviz_1_1Panel.html#a5d02e3c5ccd253442c482bb1a18d7dd6) (you haven't specified which ROS distro you are using, but it is the same for at least `noetic`, `melodic` and `kinetic`).

Thus, you are not overriding the function, but introduce a new one. You could safeguard against that [by using the `override` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880205/is-the-override-keyword-just-a-check-for-a-overridden-virtual-method) available in C++11.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [standmit](https://answers.ros.org/users/39694/standmit/) on 2021-02-18**:
Thank you!